# How to save profile photo with winter bash hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2014

Winter bash hat is disappearing when I save the profile picture to my computer. How can I save my photo with winter bash hat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a bookmarklet:

> `javascript:(function(){var avatar=$(".user-header-left .gravatar-wrapper-128 img,#avatar-card .gravatar-wrapper-164 img");var hat=avatar.closest("a").find(".hat img");var ao=avatar.offset();var ho=hat.offset();var x=Math.min(ao.left,ho.left)|0;var y=Math.min(ao.top, ho.top)|0;var w=Math.max(ao.left+avatar.width()|0,ho.left+hat.width()|0)-x;var h=Math.max(ao.top+avatar.height()|0,ho.top+hat.height()|0)-y;var ctx=$("<canvas width='"+w+"' height='"+h+"'/>").css({display:"block",clear:"both"}).insertAfter("#user-info-container,#user-card")[0].getContext("2d");ctx.drawImage(avatar[0],ao.left-x|0,ao.top-y|0);ctx.drawImage(hat[0],ho.left-x|0,ho.top-y|0)})()`

That'll draw your avatar and the hat onto a canvas. At least in Chrome you can right click -> save image on a canvas. Only works on profile pages, probably fails if you have "identicon" as your profile picture type, not tested a lot.

Answer (score 11):

There is no built-in way to do that. You can take a screenshot of it and use an image editing program to select only the part with you and your hat.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add.... while it may seems that the bash site is saved after the event ends, do not trust that.

History shows that the old bash site is removed soon before the next one starts, so you cannot use the site as a repository, unless this year our request is accepted and we get an official statement that claims the site will stay.

That said, the other answers actually got it, there is no built in way to save a screen of the hat so you have to use whatever external program you prefer.