# How can I save images of me in my hats as transparent PNGs?

Tags: discussion, images, winter-bash

I'm looking to get a PNG of my various hats on my profile pic for personal use (changing the hat I'm wearing and capturing an image of each setup somehow). I need a PNG that's either 32 × 32 or 128 × 128 pixels with a transparent background, since the hats I am wearing usually extend past my profile image and I don't want to capture (for example) the black color of the top bar that's behind it. (If they didn't, I would take a screenshot.)

Does anyone have a convenient method to get this? I don't want to spend time editing out the background, not to mention any potential problems with that and resizing.

Related questions:

- [How to save profile photo with winter bash hat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245201/323179) (It gives an error after all these years.)
- [How can I save my hats as vector images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288812/323179) (This is about vector images, which won't work for me.)

Answer (score 7):

1. If you want the highest resolution available profile image use this URL:

   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2CgS.png?s=512&512

   For 256x256 use this:

   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2CgS.png?s=256&256

   For 128x128 use this:

   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2CgS.png?s=128&128
2. Using a chrome plugin such as [SVG Export](https://svgexport.io), download the image of the hat.
3. Use an online utility to convert the SVG to a PNG format file using a converter that lets you choose one dimension to match your avatar, and transparent backgrounds: https://image.online-convert.com/convert/svg-to-png
4. The *secret* to getting an editor to extend the canvas and allow adding the hat outside the boundaries of your avatar is to use a transparent image the final size of your canvas as the bottom layer.
5. Here is a transparent 1024x1024 image:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVWug.png
6. Load the transparent image into your editor, next load your avatar, finally load the hat.

Here is the result:

> [image]

There is no "editing out the background" or resizing issues; I did this easily on my phone, it should be even easier on a desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the ideal solution, but what I did is:

1. Save my original profile picture into an 128x128 png file.
2. Save the image of the hat I want to use (you can find the original hat images [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384707/441695)).
3. Then, paste the hat image on your profile image using an image editor on your computer/mobile device.